# Python creating timestamps at different locations/classes to log function block run time

Tags: python, variables, timestamp, global

I know how to create a basic time stamp:

```
t1 = time.time()
# program runs runs
t2 = time.time()
dt = t2 - t1
```

My problem is, the program is a big giant mass, it works, but it contains thousands of lines and inter winding classes, method calls, funcs.

To sum up, this is what I want to achieve:

1. I want to plant a t1 at the middle of one classes,
2. some func calls this class, then another class from a different modules, and so on,
3. at the end of some other classes, I want to plant a t2,
4. and then at the very end, I want to output a `dt = t2 - t1`.
5. I know something about global variables, but not sure if that's doable with cross modules, I mean t1 may be from abc.py, t2 may be from 123.py, is it possible?

Comment: Hi! Have you tried the solution I proposed? Did you have any trouble with it?

Comment: I havn't because I found a different way. But I am sure your's would work and I will try it sometime later. For now I will select yours as the best answer. I still appreciate your effort nonetheless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One idea is to create a module with a global variable, that way you won't pollute the namespace much.

Here is mytimer.py:

```
import time

TIMER = None

def start():
    global TIMER
    TIMER = time.time()

def stop(msg=None):
    global TIMER
    msg = msg or "TIMER"
    if TIMER:
        print('%s -- %s' % (msg, time.time() - TIMER))
    else:
        print 'ERROR: TIMER is not set'
```

Then, suppose you start the timer in module1.py:

```
import mytimer

def somefun():
    mytimer.start()

somefun()
```

you will be able see how much time it went when you call `mytimer.stop()` in another module, here is module2.py:

```
import mytimer
import module1

mytimer.stop(msg="Timer from module1:")

# restart timer
mytimer.start()
# .. do something here
# and then get timer with specific message
mytimer.stop(msg='Finished at')
```

This should result in:

```
$ python module2.py 
Timer from module1 -- 3.81469726562e-06 sec
Finished at -- 9.53674316406e-07 sec
```